# How to use multiple cores with py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

Looking at the [py.test documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html#usage-examples) it would seem that passing `-n NUM` would specify the number of cores to be used.

My experience is the following:

```
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
```

If I try to specify it in `pytest.ini` (which is my preference) I get the same result.

I'm adding `addopts = -n4` to the `ini` file, which seems to be what the docs require.

I'm using py.test 2.8, and I've tried both python 2 and python 3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to install `xdist`

```
pip install pytest-xdist
```